# Application of Zariski's Lemma other than Hilbert's Nullstellensatz

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Zariski's Lemma is the following:

> Let $K$ be a field and $R$ be a $K$-algebra with $R=K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$
> for some $x_1,\dots,x_n\in R$. If $R$ is a field then $x_1,\dots,x_n$
> are algebraic over $K$.

Oskar Zariski used this Lemma to prove Hilbert's Nullstellensatz. Is there another non-trivial application of this Lemma?

Comment: Isn't this basically equivalent to the Nullstellensatz?

Comment: Maybe this is the Weak Nullstellensatz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Zariski's lemma to show that if $R$ is a finitely generated $\mathbf Z$-algebra, then its residue fields $R/\mathfrak m$ for maximal ideals $\mathfrak m$ are all finite. That leads to a description of all the maximal ideals in $\mathbf Z[x]$, for instance.  See Section 5 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ringtheory/maxideal-polyring.pdf).